# Flash CS3: Text appears on button mouse over or text mouse over

Tags: flash, button, mouseover, cs3

I'm new in Flash, and I already have a problem. I'm using Flash Professional CS3, and I want to create an interactive map. When the mouse is over a point on the map, some text appears at the bottom of the frame.

So, I've created a button, entered its properies by double clicking on it, went to the "over" timeline cell, inserted a keyframe and, on the main document, changed the button color and created a text field.

When I launch the player, it starts as expected. When I mouse over the button, the text appears. But, if I put the cursor over the text location, the text becomes visible! I don't want that. The text should become visible ONLY when the cursor is over the button, not at the bottom of the document.

Any idea how to achieve that?

I'm using Action script 2.0, but I didn't write any code for that. I did it via the UI.

Comment: Are you using actionscript 2 or 3?   Anyway you can share a link to your .fla

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have placed text field inside the button. If you put textfield inside the button then the textfield also behave as button. So, Place the text field outside the button. 
If it's not that case then can you put your codes?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I place the text field outside the button, how can it appear when the cursor is over the button ? I didn't write any code for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example.
make a dynamic texfield in stage.
give the instance name of texfield label.
select the button and press F9 and put the following code

```
on(rollover){
_root.label.text = "helloWorld;
}
```